# String parsed to JSON on causes AssertionError: { [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects]

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to make json objects based on the arguments to the getBooksFromDB() function, to fit into the following syntax of multiple conditions:-

`var cursor = db.collection('books').find({ $or:[{condition1},{condition2},...] });`

The database: (Mongodb)

```
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'VI\u001b\u001aQ\nÀ\r±[' },
  title: 'TestBook',
  author: 'Amresh Venugopal',
  tags: [ 'junk', 'useless book' ] }
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'V\u0002\u0000a\u001dsÔ\r¡Í' },
  title: 'BlackBook I',
  author: 'Hermaeus Mora',
  tags: [ 'skyrim', 'magic', 'armour' ] }
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'V\u0002\u000fÛ¢Så\rK¢æ' },
  title: 'BlackBook II',
  author: 'Hermaeus Mora',
  tags: [ 'skyrim', 'magic', 'shouts' ] }
```

and the code:

```
var getBooksFromDB = function(db, title, author, tags, callback){
    var query = "";

    if(typeof title !== undefined) {
        query += "{'title': '" + title + "'},";
    }

    if(typeof author !== undefined) {
        query += "{'author': '" + author + "'},";
    }

    query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(query));  
    var cursor = db.collection('books').find({
            $or:[query]
        });

    cursor.each(function(err, doc){
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if(doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });

}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    getBooksFromDB(db, "TestBook", "Amresh Venugopal", function() {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

The var `query` on console looks like:

```
{'title': 'TestBook'},{'author': 'Amresh Venugopal'}
```

The Error:

```
AssertionError: { [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue
$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects]
name: 'MongoError', message == null
```

Comment: console.log query after it has been parsed. the way you're creating [query] doesn't look correct at all. It should be failing because json keys/values must be wrapped in double quotes, not single, so you should have received an error on parsing. You didn't because you are for some reason JSON stringifying the string.

Comment: I'll try that. I used stringify just because I was getting parse error x(

Comment: yeah, that's not gonna work.

Comment: I would suggest forgetting json and just building an object/array directly. besides, manually building json is awful, even more so when you're writing javascript.